# ¿Cómo crear un Callback onSelectionChanged de un EditText en Java Android?

Tags: java, android

Mi clase donde se detecta el cambio de posición del cursor

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    private static final String TAG = MyEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

     @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSelectionChanged: selStart is " + selStart + "selEnd is " + selEnd);
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    }
}
```

en mi MainActivity

```
final MyEditText textArea = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.text_content);
```

Como capturo el evento `onSelectionChanged` des de la MainActivity, quiero obtener los valores selSart y selEnd cada vez que se actualizan, para mostrarlos en un `TextView`?

```
textArea.???
```

Comment: no entiendo los votos en contra.

Comment: Yo tampoco,si dejasen el motivo en comentarios seria de agrado.

Comment: @Webserveis He escuchado que dicen que no es necesario explicar los votos en contra, en algunos casos como este creo que sería necesario. Tal vez no entendieron la pregunta o al menos proponer para evitar errores por parte del OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirándome un motón de artículos de como diseñar un callback en Java, lo más entendedor que he encontrado a sido [how-to-define-callbacks-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android)

**MyEditText con Callback:**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    private static final String TAG = MyEditText.class.getSimpleName();

    interface OnSelectionChangedListener {
        void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd);
    }

private OnSelectionChangedListener callback = null;

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
    if (this.callback != null) this.callback.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

}

public void setOnSelectionChanged(OnSelectionChangedListener callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

}
```

Para usarlo en MainActivity

```
final MyEditText textArea = (MyEditText) findViewById(R.id.text_content);
textArea.setOnSelectionChanged( new MyEditText.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        Log.d(TAG, "callbackCall() called with: " + "selStart = [" + selStart + "], selEnd = [" + selEnd + "]");
    }
});
```